# I need to create relationships In tableau between 5 different data sources. all data sources share 3 columns in common while 3 share an additonal one

Tags: relationship, tableau-api, tableau-prep

[image: example of what im trying but this doesnt feel right]

Do I need to drag the files and have multiple versions of thes files in the relationship tab (such as hourly steps 0,1 and 2).

I feel like there is definitely an easier way to do this.

the three "hourly" files share an additional column, while all the rest just share 3.

I've tried setting up in the image orovided above but this seems wrong, and takes a long time to load on tableau public.